# Removing duplicate PHAssets from an array?

Tags: arrays, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, phasset

I'm using third party library called [BSImagePicker](https://github.com/mikaoj/BSImagePicker) to select multiple images from the photo library. I can set maximum `PHAssets` to be selected, but the problem comes when I display the `BSImagePickerController` to choose more photos. Those `PHAssets` are just additionally added to the `selectedAssets` and practically duplicates the images. I tried to remove the duplicates `PHAsset` and images using but it's not working:

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
mutating func removeDuplicates() {
    var result = [Element]()
    for value in self {
        if !result.contains(value) {
            result.append(value)
        }
    }
    self = result
   }
}

func presentBSImagePickerController(vc: BSImagePickerViewController) {
        self.bs_presentImagePickerController(vc, animated: true,
                                             select: { (asset: PHAsset) -> Void in

        }, deselect: { (asset: PHAsset) -> Void in
            // User deselected an assets.

        }, cancel: { (assets: [PHAsset]) -> Void in
            // User cancelled. And this where the assets currently selected.

        }, finish: { (assets: [PHAsset]) -> Void in


            // User finished with these assets

            for i in 0..<assets.count  {
                self.selectedAssets.append(assets[i])
            }
            self.selectedAssets.removeDuplicates()

            self.convertAssetToImages()

        }, completion: nil)
    }

    func convertAssetToImages() -> Void {

        if selectedAssets.count != 0 {

            for i in 0..<selectedAssets.count {

                let manager = PHImageManager.default()
                let option = PHImageRequestOptions()
                var thumbnail = UIImage()
                option.isSynchronous = true

                manager.requestImage(for: selectedAssets[i], targetSize: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: option, resultHandler: {(result, info)->Void in
                    thumbnail = result!

                })

                let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(thumbnail, 0.7)
                let newImage = UIImage(data: data!)

                self.photosArray.append(newImage! as UIImage)
                self.photosArray.removeDuplicates()
                print(self.photosArray.removeDuplicates())

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.collectionView.reloadData() // reloads the collection view on main thread
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with

```
for i in 0..<assets.count  {
    self.selectedAssets.append(assets[i])
}
self.selectedAssets.removeDuplicates()
```

...is that your `removeDuplicates` (apart from being intolerably slow!) simply assumes that PHAsset equality is the mark of a duplicated image. It isn't. An asset is just a temporary representative of what's in the library. What you want to know is whether the *local identifier* of an asset matches that of one that you already have. I would suggest this:

```
var ids = Set(self.selectedAssets.map {$0.localIdentifier})
for asset in assets  {
    if !ids.contains(asset.localIdentifier) {
        ids.insert(asset.localIdentifier)
        self.selectedAssets.append(asset)
    }
}
```

We make a list of all the local identifiers of the assets we already have. Then we append an asset (and its identifier) only if its identifier is not in the list. This will be *much* faster (because Set `contains` is much faster than Array `contains`), and should also prevent "the same photo" from appearing twice.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this. Thank you for the explanation, but for some reason, the effect is the same. To be honest, I dont know why. I've replaced the problematic code you've pointed out with the suggested one and the result is still the same. If i select 2 assets the first time, then present the picker again and select another one, the first 2 are duplicated and the third one is added (but actually, in the `UICollectionViewCell` i see 5 images in total

Comment: The question is not about what you see in your collection view, but about what happens when that code runs. Could you check in the debugger? Put a breakpoint on `self.selectedAssets.append` and see how many times it is called. If it is _not_ called for the duplicates, then my code is working and that's the end of this question. If that doesn't help with your collection view, that would be a _different_ question; there was no collection view in your original question, only a claim that duplicates were being added to `selectedAssets`.

Comment: Your code works great. The problem was that I had to empty the `photoArray` before it convert the `PHAsset` into an image. But now it works. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're very welcome. Thanks for the tickmark too; I'm not sure I deserve it! My code improves yours (for speed if nothing else), but it probably wasn't the real solution to the problem, which was in your management of the collection view data model, totally outside the scope of the question you posed. We call that an _x-y question:_ you _assume_ the problem lies here so you ask a question about it, but in reality the problem lies elsewhere. There was _no_ collection view in your question, so it was impossible for me to guess that!

Comment: Yes, you're right and I understand that. I managed to figure out the `UICollectionView` (which was more like an `array`) problem myself. It was a simply fix but yet, sometimes you just don't see the problem even if it's right in front of your eyes!

Answer (score 0):

Step: 1. This code should be sufficient:

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
mutating func removeDuplicates() {
    var result = [Element]()
    for value in self {
        if !result.contains(value) {
            result.append(value)
        }
    }
    self = result
}
```

}

Step: 2. "selectedAssets" which is PHAssets type array, you have to remove all the assets form "selectedAssets" array. Because you are showing multiImage from "photosArray" this array always has your image, and "selectedAssets" array always has reference value after being deleted. So remove all assets form  "selectedAssets" array before for loop which is shown below. Or if you have any query, feel free to ask anything to me(Mohit Tomer)

```
// MARK:- Selecting Multiple Image From Gallery.
func showingImagePicker() {
    let vc = BSImagePickerViewController()
    var ids = Set(self.selectedAssets.map {$0.localIdentifier})
    vc.maxNumberOfSelections = 5
    vc.cancelButton.tintColor = UIColor.red
    vc.selectionCharacter = "✓"

    self.bs_presentImagePickerController(vc, animated: true, select: { (asset: PHAsset) -> Void in
        print("Selected: \(asset)")
    }, deselect: { (asset: PHAsset) -> Void in
        print("Deselected: \(asset)")
    }, cancel: { (assets: [PHAsset]) -> Void in
        print("Cancel: \(assets)")
    }, finish: { (assets: [PHAsset]) -> Void in
        print("Finish: \(assets)")

        self.selectedAssets.removeAll()
        for asset in assets  {
            if !ids.contains(asset.localIdentifier) {
                ids.insert(asset.localIdentifier)
                self.selectedAssets.append(asset)
            }
        }
        self.convertingAssetToImage()

    }, completion: nil)
}




    func convertingAssetToImage() -> Void {
    var thumbnail = UIImage()
    if selectedAssets.count != 0 {

        for item in selectedAssets {
            let manager = PHImageManager.default()
            let option = PHImageRequestOptions()
            option.isSynchronous = true
            manager.requestImage(for: item, targetSize: CGSize(width: 200.0, height: 200.0), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: option, resultHandler: { (result, info) -> Void in
                print("result", result as Any)
                print("info", info as Any)
                thumbnail = result!
            })

            self.photoArray.append(thumbnail)
            self.photoDataArray.append(thumbnail.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5))

        }

    }
}
```